# automatic notification that show me if the date_end is close to the user

Tags: symfony, notifications, symfony-3.4

hello everybody I'm new with symfony 3.4 .I'm struggling with making a automatic notification that show me if the date_end is close to the user.I make a lot of research about notification  bundles ,taskscheduling, crone none of them is usful

Comment: There is lots of bundles and library available  for implement notifications. You question seems  incomplete. You have to describe which type notification wants to need like email notification,  sms notfication.

Comment: i need an automatic notification appears when my date is close to the end and i want it to be showen in my dashboard  no need for email or sms

Comment: You can do in simple way:  1) create action  where you have to check your date_end with current date and return appropriate repsonse. 2) you have render such action in your base twig. hence ,you will get response whatever you page called.